# Is urldecode cross platform?

Tags: urlencode, urldecode

I'm presuming it is cross platform, as it's an age old feature of many frameworks...

However in practice, can url decoding be assumed to be cross platform?

For example urlencoding in .net framework and then decoding on iPhone / objective-c or Android.

Comment: One would hope the [standard](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) is respected by everyone, but I suppose you'd need to check specific frameworks to be certain.

Comment: The specific *function* is likely different on every platform; but there should be a function which can properly encode and decode values according to the RFC on any platform that can deal with HTTP.

Comment: Thanks, I've reworded it to be more explicit.

Comment: Yes, you can assume the function will work if the platform has implemented it correctly based on the RFC. If not, you can't. There's no definitive answer here, I doubt anyone one person knows whether every applicable language and framework on the planet implements the RFC properly. They _should_ be doing so, but they don't _have_ to. Beyond that there isn't much to be said about it really

Comment: True, good point - I suppose it was looking for advice on what people have found in practice or if their was an authoritative resource discussing url encoding between popular frameworks. Similar to how there are resources discussing interoperability between web services. But I think you're probably right in general it's going to be RFC we hope.